# ElasticSearch is crashing while loading data using post request

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch running in my localhost for some POC project . I have a single Node i.e, my pc. A c++ app that i developed keeps indexing documents into elasticsearch periodically . It was working fine until recently es is not accepting anymore documents . Es is rejecting with following error .

```
[2019-05-22T14:23:54,340][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [rMNTUrd] started
[2019-05-22T14:25:05,762][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] [rMNTUrd] path: /healthbeatprocess/_doc, params: {index=healthbeatprocess, type=_doc}
org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException: [healthbeatprocess][3] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[healthbeatprocess][3]] containing [index {[healthbeatprocess][_doc][TgC_3moBGx_RfE7qYsyv], source[{"@timestamp":"2019-05-22T14:23:59.000Z","ExecutionState":0,"HandleCount":0,"KernelModeTime":2147483647,"Name":"System Idle Process","OtherOperationCount":0,"OtherTransferCount":0,"PageFaults":8,"PageFileUsage":56,"ParentProcessId":0,"PeakPageFileUsage":56,"PeakVirtualSize":8192,"Priority":0,"ProcessId":0,"QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage":1,"QuotaPagedPoolUsage":0,"QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage":1,"QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage":0,"ReadOperationCount":0,"ReadTransferCount":0,"SessionId":0,"ThreadCount":4,"UserModeTime":0,"VirtualSize":8192,"WriteOperationCount":0,"WriteTransferCount":0,"CreationDate":"2019-05-20T14:57:08.19Z","cpu_percent":25.000000}]}]]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase.retryBecauseUnavailable(TransportReplicationAction.java:932) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase.retryIfUnavailable(TransportReplicationAction.java:778) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:731) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase$2.onTimeout(TransportReplicationAction.java:892) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:317) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:244) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:559) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:624) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
[2019-05-22T14:27:50,436][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] [rMNTUrd] path: /healthbeatprocess/_doc, params: {index=healthbeatprocess, type=_doc}
org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException: [healthbeatprocess][3] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[healthbeatprocess][3]] containing [index {[healthbeatprocess][_doc][VwDB3moBGx_RfE7q5swB], source[{"@timestamp":"2019-05-22T14:26:46.000Z","ExecutionState":0,"HandleCount":0,"KernelModeTime":84375000,"Name":"Registry","OtherOperationCount":1098,"OtherTransferCount":3827,"PageFaults":447188,"PageFileUsage":3424,"ParentProcessId":4,"PeakPageFileUsage":316800,"PeakVirtualSize":460234752,"Priority":8,"ProcessId":104,"QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage":21,"QuotaPagedPoolUsage":381,"QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage":38,"QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage":882,"ReadOperationCount":4,"ReadTransferCount":2048,"SessionId":0,"ThreadCount":3,"UserModeTime":0,"VirtualSize":197369856,"WriteOperationCount":16136,"WriteTransferCount":376434688,"CreationDate":"2019-05-20T14:57:03.58Z","cpu_percent":0.000000}]}]]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase.retryBecauseUnavailable(TransportReplicationAction.java:932) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase.retryIfUnavailable(TransportReplicationAction.java:778) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:731) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase$2.onTimeout(TransportReplicationAction.java:892) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:317) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:244) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:559) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:624) [elasticsearch-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
```

Currently I have 1.5 million records in that index . Is it refusing because there is a limit on the number of records per index . Please help me in getting es working again .

Comment: how many data node, master node and shard do you have?

Comment: i got the following response when i queried for health`{b'active_shards_percent': b'48.4%',
 b'cluster': b'elasticsearch',
 b'epoch': b'1558591039',
 b'init': b'0',
 b'max_task_wait_time': b'-',
 b'node.data': b'1',
 b'node.total': b'1',
 b'pending_tasks': b'0',
 b'pri': b'15',
 b'relo': b'0',
 b'shards': b'15',
 b'status': b'red',
 b'timestamp': b'05:57:19',
 b'unassign': b'16'}`

Comment: i found a link that is explaining something [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/red-cluster-states-and-search-query-response-codes/41275) . "As described https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cluster_health.html 7 when a cluster is in RED state search queries will return partial results, and indexing into that shard will return an exception."